# Interface method that has different parameters in Java

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

Looking for some guidance on designing some code in Java.

Currently I have something like this....

```
@Service
class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private FilterSoldOut filterSoldOut;
    @Autowired
    private FilterMinPriceThreshold filterMinPriceThreshold;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        List<Product> products = //...code to get some products

        // Returns list of in-stock products
        products = filterSoldOut.doFilter(products); 

        // Returns list of products above min price
        products = filterMinPriceThreshold.doFilter(minPrice, products);

        return products; 
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is create a Filter interface with a doFilter method and then in SomeService create a List filters, which is autowired by Spring. Then in the getProducts method I can iterate the filters list and invoke doFilter. This way in the future I can, create new classes that implement the Filter interface and add them to the list via Spring configuration, and have the new filter applied without having to change the code.

But, the problem is that the parameters to the doFilter method can be different. I've read about the Command Pattern, and the Visitor Pattern but they don't quite seem to fit the bill.

Can anyone suggest a good pattern to achieve what I've described?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into `varargs`, although that may mean having to cast everything inside the `method` from `Object`. You might want to take the same approach that you took with your filters, with your parameters, and create a common interface (or abstract class) for them.

Comment: what part is responsible to decide about the values of your filter parameters? If that decision could be made prior to setting the filter you wouldn't need them. Or invert the dependency: let Service implement something (e.g. `FilterableByPrice#getMinPrice()`) that is used by `filter.applyTo(Service)` to find the right parameters while service can still decide about the parameters.

Comment: Could you provide any example of the different doFilter parameters? In what situation would you need different parameters?

Comment: @zapi; The service gets an object that has the values, it passes only the values a Filter needs. I could pass the whole FilterValues object but I have a case where I'm passing a parameter that comes from else where.

Comment: @stan0; there are a couple of doFilter methods in the example above, they have different argument lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**old**:

> I'd suggest you setting the filter state at construction time or at
>   least before you `getProducts()`.
>
> In your example with the two filters one of them is (probably)
>   checking a database for availability of the product and the other one
>   is comparing the product's price to some preset value. This value
>   (`minPrice`) is known before the filter is applied. It can
>   also be said that the filter depends on it, or that it's part of the
>   filter's state. Therefore I'd recommend you putting the
>   `minPrice` inside the filter at construction time (or via a
>   setter) and then only pass the list of products you want to filter.
>   Use the same pattern for your other filters.

**new suggestion** (came up with it after the comments):

You can create a single object (AllFiltersState) that holds all the values for all the filters. In your controller set whatever criteria you need in this object (minPrice, color, etc.) and pass it to every filter along the products - doFilter(allFiltersState, products).

Comment: It's a fair idea, but I'm trying to avoid having the controller know what kinds of Filters there are. To set the state as you suggest, I'd have to do instance of checks.

Comment: Your point is correct but what I meant was to set the state when you create the filter (probably before it's passed to the controller).

Comment: Oh I see, the values can change at runtime, this is why the values are passed to the filters.

Comment: Then create a single object (AllFiltersState) that holds all the values for all the filters. In your controller set whatever criteria you need in this object (minPrice, color, etc.) and pass it to the filter along the products - doFilter(allFiltersState, products)

Comment: It's basically what I've done ended up doing, not the greatest solution because there's that chance something is added/removed in the AllFiltersState object that will affect more than one filter.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Some are complicated, some are simpler. The simplest one would be to use `varargs` or an array of `Object` elements. The problem here is that you have to cast each objetc to its proper type in order to use them and that can be a little tricky if there are multiple types in an unknown order.

Another option is to use a `Map<String,Object>` (which you can wrap in a class of your own if required, something lile `FilterParams`) that stores parameters based on a name, and you can then obtain them and cast them accordingly.

---

#### Edit

Considering that the parameters vary on runtime, you'll need someone *"well informed"* about the current configuration.

Not pattern-wise but I'd rather keep it simple without using too many fancy names. What about introducing a `FilterConfigurator` that has a simple overloaded method `configure` that recieves the particular filter and configures it based on its type?. This configurator is the *informed* entity that knows the current values for those parameters.

The goal is to rid `Service` from the responsibility of configuring a filter.

In addition, if you create your `Filter` class, you'll be able to implement a single `doFilter` that you can invoke without changes.

There's another Idea... and it involves a `FilterFactory` that creates **and** initializes filters, thus having a filter 100% configured from scratch. This factory can rely on the very same `FilterConfigurer` or do it itself.

Comment: I did think about the Map suggestion, but that couples the Service with the Filters since they both need to know about the keys that are used. Changing the key in the map.put() would mean changing the map.get() call.

Comment: @C0deAttack True, in a way, but the `Service` shouldn't be in charge of configuring the parameters. I'm wondering about something... but it involves changing the approach you take. Why should the service provide the parameters on the first place? Why can't you configure a filter prior to its use instead of providing a set of params on the `doFilter` method?.

Comment: @C0deAttack Note: By configuring I mean that _someone_ (something, actually) has to initialize them, so it might set up its required and particular parameters as well.

Comment: It's a good question Gamb, and it's because the value of parameters can change at runtime.

Comment: I did also think about creating a new Filter instance each time but this part of the code would execute quite frequently so I didn't want to create objects with new state when I could just pass in the values.

Comment: @C0deAttack Well, you can avoid creating a filter each time, still you'll need to pass in the values (going back to your original situation) if you don't want to reconfigure the filter should any configuration field change. It's a trade-off, you have to find out how much are you willing to give in order to take.

Answer (score 0):

As Cris say you can use next function definition:

```
  public List<Product> doFilter(Object...args) {
    if (args.length != 2)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (! (args[0] instanceof String))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (! (args[2] instanceof Integer))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    String stringArgument = (String) args[0];
    Integer integerArgument = (Integer) args[1];

    // your code here

    return ...;
  }
```

or with command pattern:

```
public interface Command {
}

public class FirstCommand implements Command {
  private String string;

  // constructor, getters and setters
}

public class SecondCommand implements Command {
  private Integer integer;

  // constructor, getters and setters
}

// first service function
public List<Product> doFilter(Command command) {
  if (command instanceof FirstCommand)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  FirstCommand firstCommand = (FirstCommand) command;

  return ...;
}

// second service function
public List<Product> doFilter(Command command) {
  if (command instanceof SecondCommand)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  SecondCommand secondCommand = (SecondCommand) command;

  return ...;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, i understand your question. And think you can create various session scoped filters.

```
@Service
class SomeService {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private List<Filter> filters;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        List<Product> products = //...code to get some products

        if (filters != null) {
          for (Filter filter : filters)
            products = filter.doFilter(products);
        }

        return products; 
    }
}
```

And then create filters with settings fields:

```
public PriceFilter implements Filter {
  private Integer minPrice;
  private Integer maxPrice;

  // getters and setters

  public List<Product> doFilter(List<Product> products) {
     // implementation here
  }
}

public ContentFilter implements Filter {
  private String regexp;

  // getters and setters

  public List<Product> doFilter(List<Product> products) {
     // implementation here
  }
}
```

Then user can configure this filters for session and use service function `getProducts` to get result.

Comment: @C0deAttack: why you don't want to use command pattern? or varargs?

Comment: With varargs as Objects and then cast? I'd have to know the order of the data types to cast safely, not great. I read about the Command pattern and I didn't see how to have parameters of different length and types since they interface is the same with regards to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Having a list of filters getting autowired is not a very good approach to solve your problem.
Every filter depends on different types of parameters which would need to be passed to the `doFilter` method. Needing to do so makes the approach highly unflexible. Yes you could use varargs but it would just create a mess. That's why it's probably easier to implement a builder to build you a chain of filters to be applied to the collection of products. Adding new filters to the builder becomes a trivial task. The Builder Pattern is very useful when a lot of different parameters are at play.

Consider having this interface:

```
public interface CollectionFilter<T> {
    public Collection<T> doFilter(Collection<T> collection);
}
```

A filter chaining class which applies all filters to the collection:

```
public class CollectionFilterChain<T> {
    private final List<CollectionFilter<T>> filters;

    public CollectionFilterChain(List<CollectionFilter<T>> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    public Collection<T> doFilter(Collection<T> collection) {
        for (CollectionFilter<T> filter : filters) {
            collection = filter.doFilter(collection);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

The two `CollectionFilter<T>` implementations:

```
public class InStockFilter<T> implements CollectionFilter<T> {

    public Collection<T> doFilter(Collection<T> collection) {
        // filter
    }
}


public class MinPriceFilter<T> implements CollectionFilter<T> {

    private final float minPrice;

    public MinPriceFilter(float minPrice) {
        this.minPrice = minPrice;
    }

    public Collection<T> doFilter(Collection<T> collection) {
        // filter
    }
}
```

And a builder to let you build the filter chain in a easy way:

```
public class CollectionFilterChainBuilder<T> {
    List<CollectionFilter<T>> filters;

    public CollectionFilterChainBuilder() {
        filters = new ArrayList<CollectionFilter<T>>();
    }

    public CollectionFilterChainBuilder<T> inStock() {
        filters.add(new InStockFilter<T>());
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionFilterChainBuilder<T> minPrice(float price) {
        filters.add(new MinPriceFilter<T>(price));
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionFilterChain<T> build() {
        return new CollectionFilterChain<T>(filters);
    }
}
```

With the builder it's easy to create a filter chain as follows:

```
CollectionFilterChainBuilder<Product> builder = 
    new CollectionFilterChainBuilder();

CollectionFilterChain<Product> filterChain = 
    builder.inStock().minPrice(2.0f).build();

Collection<Product> filteredProducts = 
    filterChain.doFilter(products);
```

In a more dynamic settings you could use the builder like:

```
CollectionFilterChainBuilder<Product> builder = new CollectionFilterChainBuilder();

if (filterInStock) {
    builder.inStock();
}

if (filterMinPrice) {
    builder.minPrice(minPrice);
}

// build some more
```